# how to access this class in css

Tags: css

```
<form name="fc">
         <div class="input-text">
         <input type="text" id="postquestion" name="postquestion" style="font-size:12px;"class="ps" value="" placeholder="What's Your Question..?" data-mini="true" />
         <a href="#dialog" class="dig" value="" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-inline="true" data-rel="dialog" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
         <input type="submit" value="Ask" class="ask" data-inline="true" data-mini="true"data-theme="b"/>
      </div>
</form>
```

this code is not working

```
.ask
{
margin-top:-10px;
}
```

i'm newbie to css , please help me. http://jsfiddle.net/shreeramns/4dRuP/

Comment: What have you tried? Please explain what you want to do? Actually this works

Comment: No problem in class use properties as per need.

Comment: @ozkanozlu i want to align the Ask button and reduce width of the button

Comment: @Sriram: Since your problem depends not only on `.ask` you should create a demo, for example on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Your button looks aligned to me without fiddling with margin-top:  http://jsfiddle.net/hXwxz/

Comment: @Zeta here and i cant able to change width of text box. please see this http://jsfiddle.net/shreeramns/4dRuP/

Comment: @cimmanon but it's not aligned in my laptop screen,look at this https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7s0BYiHsMBtNnRPanNkOUtlc2c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Sriram How were you expecting anyone to reproduce that when you didn't provide the code that showed the problem?  You aren't using the `.ask` class anywhere in your fiddle.  However, using a negative margin-top is not the correct way to go about fixing this problem.

Comment: @cimmanon here http://jsfiddle.net/shreeramns/4dRuP/

Answer (score 3):

`input` is an inline-element, thus it cannot have any margin applied. You need to make it a block-level element:

```
.ask
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top:-10px;
}
```

Furthermore, you shouldn't use negative margins if possible, use positioning instead.

Comment: it tried but nothing comes. please look at this.
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7s0BYiHsMBtNnRPanNkOUtlc2c/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

you may have to use `float:left` for both of the button and textbox

```
   .ask{
        margin-top:-10px;
        display:inline;
        position:relative;
        float:left;
    }
    .ps{
        float:left;
        display:inline;
    }
```

Preview >> http://jsfiddle.net/vmyc8/